# How to make Thread.Sleep accept textBox text?

Tags: c#

So I have this simple spammer, and I would like to allow people to decide the interval between the text.
I use Thread.Sleep for the interval, so how do I allow Thread.Sleep to allow the numbers from the textBox? (I set my textBox to numbers only)

```
if (p != null)
        {   // send spam to it
            IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(h);
            SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }
```

This is my spammer code, and this is my code for numbers only textBox.

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(richTextBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.");
            richTextBox1.Text.Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if anyone helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep(Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text));

Comment: Note that while correct this is not going to help OP as UI will be frozen 100% of the time :)